# How to automate creating a git pull-request using hub through jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, github, automation, pull-request

I am trying to setup a Jenkins Job which can automate the job of creating a pull-request using hub. I am able to create the pull-request when I run the command from terminal but it fails when I execute it from my Jenkins Job

The gist of what I am trying to achieve here is from a Jenkins Job, I should be able to create a new branch, make some changes to the branch, push it back to the repo and then raise a PR and send a mail to all the reviewers with the Pull-request URL.

I found that hub(git wrapper) will be able to help me with that, I installed it on my CentOS and made all the required configuration changes for hub to work. When I execute the command from my command line, it works like a charm but when I run it from my Jenkins Job it fails with forbidden error

```
HUB_VERBOSE=1 hub pull-request -m "<commit-msg>" -b "<master>" -h "<my-branch>" -r <reviewer>
```

Expected: `https://git.xxxx.com/<org>/<repo>/pull/34` but I am getting

```
Authorization: token [REDACTED]
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json;charset=utf-8
Error getting current user: Get https://git.xxxx.com/api/v3/user: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the solution by unsetting our organisation firewall and also by using the absolute path for hub commands